# What is rank invariance?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-transformations, physics, statistical-mechanics

I work in the area of soft matter and recently I have been reading a paper that talks about developing a new optimization algorithm for statistical physics problems.

- [Turning statistical physics models into materials design engines](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1509316112).

In this paper, the authors mention "rank invariance" and "invertible reparametrization". I went through some websites but couldn't find the proper explanation.

Comment: This is a very bad paper because mathematical symbols are poorly explained.

Comment: The mathematical symbols of the paper as you say are actually universally used in physics.

Comment: Perhaps it’s referring to the constant rank theorem, which says in essence that the main theorem of matrix row-reduction also holds for differentiable maps: that you can find a local change of variables that makes the map look “nice.”